# WebPack: Entrypoint underfined

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am doing one of the [Tutorial](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-webpack-babel/#How_to_set_up_React_webpack_and_Babel_the_HTML_webpack_plugin) of using React, WebPack and Babel together.

While everything worked as intended(built, compile, and render correctly).

I am getting an error from webpack, that said

```
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = ./index.html
    [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 666 bytes {0} [built]
```

My WebPack configuration file looks like following:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

And My file structure looks like this:

```
WebPack_Demo
  -dist
  -node_modules
  -src
    -javascript
      -components
        -Component1.js
        -Component2.js
    -index.html
    -index.js
  -.babelrc
  - package-lock.json
  - webpack.config.js
```

Someone else is also getting the error following this tutorial but the author does not address that. Even though it does not affect the app, I still wanted to know how to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add the "entry" and "output" properties to your webpack config file.

Your output should have a "path" pointing to a folder where the bundled files are stored.

Then the "filename" in HtmlWebpackPlugin should point to that folder

This is how is mine setup:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: path.resolve(__dirname, '.','index.js')
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.', 'build'),   // ATTENTION
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       template: path.resolve('.', 'src', 'index.html'),
       chunks: [chunks],
       filename: path.join('.', 'build', 'index.html'),  // ATTENTION
    }),
    ....
  ],
  ....
}
```

Comment: what does template do?

Comment: Template is the path to your basic html file. Webpack will inject all the dependencies (js, css) to it at the compile time.

Comment: Ok,but aren't entry point and output not required in Webpack 4 tho?

Comment: There are many things that are optional, but you will have to set them up for certain things to happen... If my answer helped please upvote or accept as an answer. Thank you.